# Zooming or enhancing performance on ZXing

Tags: xamarin, zxing, zxing.net

I'm using ZXing.Mobile.Forms (ZxingScannerPage) in a Xamarin project for an app in which users would have to scan QR Codes and barcodes that are fairly high up (say, around 3 to 4 meters from the ground). The problem is, it's too far for the camera to detect!

I've already tried on more than one phone, one of them being fairly high end. Is there a way to use a zooming functionality, or to enhance the scanner's maximum range? If not, is there a better alternative to ZXing? Or will I just have to tell my bosses to hang all the labels lower?